# OpenFOAM SE Proposal

Tags: discussion

As there are many people on scicomp interested in CFD applications, I want to announce to you all that there is an active proposal on SE for OpenFOAM. OpenFOAM is a widely used open-source C++ based PDE solver based on the finite volume method.  The proposal has now reached the "committment phase", requiring a critical mass of users in order to launch into a beta site.

If you are interested in asking programming questions or other CFD related questions within the scope of OpenFOAM, please consider committing to the OpenFOAM proposal below:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88229/openfoam-technology